# Distribution of certain variable - can't find mistake.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve one problem, I arrive with a very good looking answer, but it's precisely a half of what it is supposed to be. Here is a problem:

> We take a stick of length 4 and we break it in any random place on it.
>   The place of breaking is a random variable with uniform distribution
>   U[0,4]. We then take the shorter of these two parts, and set it as one
>   side of a rectangle; the rest of the stick is broken in two more
>   parts, to create other sides of rectangle. Calculate the distribution
>   of area of that rectangle.

Let $X$ be the variable representing the breaking point. If so, then variable $Y$ - area looks like this:
$$Y=
\begin{cases}
X(2-X), &X\leq 2\\
(4-X)(X-2), &X>2\\
\end{cases}
$$

I calculate the distribution in a tradiltional way. We clearly see that $Y\in [0,1]$, so for any $t\in[0,1]$
\begin{align*}
P(Y\leq t)&=P(X(2-X)\leq t)P(X\leq 2)+P((4-X)(X-2)\leq t)P(X> 2)=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{1-\sqrt{1-t}}\frac{1}{4}dt+\int_{1+\sqrt{1-t}}^{2}\frac{1}{4}dt+\int_{2}^{3-\sqrt{1-t}}\frac{1}{4}dt+\int_{3+\sqrt{1-t}}^{4}\frac{1}{4}dt\right]=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-t})
\end{align*}

And the answer clearly should be $(1-\sqrt{1-t})$. It looks like the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor is not needed, but it comes from the total probability of event $P(Y\leq t)$ after partitioning it into two events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first contribution to $P(Y\leqslant t)$ should be
$$
P(X(2-X)\leqslant t,X\leqslant2)=\int_0^{1-\sqrt{1-t}}\frac14\mathrm dx+\int_{1+\sqrt{1-t}}^2\frac14\mathrm dx.
$$
which, together with the analogous modification of the second contribution $P((4-X)(X-2)\leqslant t,X\geqslant2)$, leads indeed to $P(Y\leqslant t)=1-\sqrt{1-t}$.

Note that $P(X(2-X)\leqslant t,X\leqslant2)\ne P(X(2-X)\leqslant t)P(X\leqslant2)$, and likewise that $P((4-X)(X-2)\leqslant t,X\geqslant2)\ne P((4-X)(X-2)\leqslant t)P(X\geqslant2)$.

Comment: But why? If I have an event $B$, and the whole event space can be partitioned into two events $A_1, A_2$, then $P(B)=P(B|A_1)P(A_1)+P(B|A_2)P(A_2)$. Here $B$ is $Y\leq t$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $X\leq 2$ and $X>2$.

Comment: Yes, but you never computed the $P(B|A_i)$.

Comment: I think I did: $P(B|A_i)$ is probability that $Y\leq t$ if we know that something happens with $X$. So this is either $P(X(2-X)\leq t)$ or $P((4-X)(X-2))$

Comment: Using $P(B|A_1)=P(Y\leqslant t|X\leqslant2)=P(B\cap A_1)/P(A_1)=P(X(2-X)\leqslant t,X\leqslant2)/P(X\leqslant2)$, one cannot go wrong. Obviously, you went wrong since you get an extrafactor of $2$. I showed you the exact point where you went wrong. What's next?

Comment: Ah, now I see where I made a mistake. Apparently $P(X(2-X))$ is $P(B\cap A_1)$, and not $P(B|A_1)$. Now I understand.